AWS API Gateway timeout limit beyond 29 seconds
I'm working on an AWS lambda code with an API request as its trigger.
I want to extend the timeout limit of my API Gateway beyond 29 seconds, which, as I understand, became possible quite recently, but I don't really understand the way to do it:
As documentation says - "You can raise the integration timeout to greater than 29 seconds for Regional REST APIs and private REST APIs, but this might require a reduction in your account-level throttle quota limit". Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find information about how the "account-level throttle quota limit" can be changed.
I was hoping asking here might be helpful.
Here's the documentation I mentioned earlier:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2024/06/amazon-api-gateway-integration-timeout-limit-29-seconds/#:~:text=Amazon%20API%20Gateway%20now%20enables,prior%20limit%20of%2029%20seconds.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-execution-service-limits-table


Request a quota increase to the Maximum integration timeout in milliseconds value.

If I am not mistaken you need to contact the AWS Support Center (as I believe Anon Coward has linked in the comments) for such a throttle increase.
This is mentioned in the documentation and it seems that, unfortunately, you cannot do it yourself.
